# React state doesn't refresh value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm now learning React and I have a problem with re-rendering component.
App.js code:

```
function App() {
const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(INITIAL_EXPENSES);
const addNewExpenseHandler = (expense) => {
    setExpenses((prevState) => {
        return [expense, ...prevState];
    }, changeYearHandler(filteredYear));
};

const filterExpenses = (expenses, year) => {
    const newFilteredExpenses = expenses.filter((expense) => {
        if (String(expense.date.getFullYear()) === year) {
            return expense;
        }
    });
    return newFilteredExpenses;
};
const [filteredYear, setFilteredYear] = useState('2019');
const [filteredExpenses, setFilteredExpenses] = useState(
    filterExpenses(expenses, filteredYear)
);
const changeYearHandler = (value) => {
    setFilteredYear(
        value,
        setFilteredExpenses(() => {
            const newValue = filterExpenses(expenses, value);
            return newValue;
        })
    );
};
return (
    <>
        <NewExpense onAddNewExpense={addNewExpenseHandler} />
        <ExpenseFilter expenses={expenses} />
        <ShowExpenses
            onChangeYear={changeYearHandler}
            data={filteredExpenses}
        />
    </>
);
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that `filteredExpenses` isn't up-to-date. It's always retarded and it's the previous state. I was trying to call a `changeYearHandler` in callback of `setExpenses` and `setFilteredExpense` inside `setFilteredYear` but it's still doesn't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you're using a roundabout way to filter your `expenses`. What about just creating a memoized version of a `filteredExpenses` directly, using [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)?

```
const filteredExpenses = useMemo(() => {
    return expenses.filter((expense) => {
        if (String(expense.date.getFullYear()) === filteredYear) {
            return expense;
        }
    });
}, [expenses, filteredYear]);
```

The dependency array will ensure that whenever `expenses` or `filteredYear` changes, then `filteredExpenses` will recompute and return a new filtered array (that is subsequently cached).